# How do I handle exception when use fake email address in laravel 7 default registration system

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am using Laravel 7 and Guzzle. 
In default laravel registration and email verification system , there are no problem when user registration with a real email.
 **But there is a problem when user try to registration with a fake email , it throw a exception like this**

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org/messages.mime`
resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` 
response: { "message": "Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authoriz (truncated...)
```

**and it also insert data in database.**

**I need such solution.**

**When user try to registration with fake email address then :-**

- How to I prevent registration
- How to redirect with message,
- for example:

```
    if(email send fail in user email address)
    {
        stop registration;
        redirect('/home')->whith('message','This email address is not real');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this manually. You are not sure whether the email is valid or fake while the registration process. You can follow the following steps

1. Complete the registration process and save data into database
2. Try to send the confirmation email.
3. If you get the error response from email sending then delete the registration data from the database and redirect to `/home` and showing the error message.

Comment: I think you will get success or error code in the response from mailgun. Look at the response both of valid email address and fake email

Comment: Give your registration controller and the code of email sending. And also the response from mailgun for both fake eami and valid email

Comment: I am using default laravel registration system.

Comment: But you have implemented email sending option with mailgun. update your questions and provide the response from mailgun for both fake eami and valid email. If I do not get the response how can I give you the solutions?

Comment: I think in laravel 7  there are no need to implement email sending option. I want say you again when i will try to registration with a valid and real email like nakulxxx@gmail.com then every thing is ok, I get mail and also registration is successful. But when I will try to registration with a fake email like egfheujdh@hfjhdjfh then the server throw me an exception (This exception I was shown in my question) .    I need just a solution like, If it throws an exception then how do I catch it? If I can catch it I can redirect...